# Delay link redirect

Tags: php, jquery

I have a few external links on my site and when one of them is clicked I am also using jQuery ajax to set a variable into session, so that when a user is back from the other site the variable is available. Sometimes, though, it seems that the redirect happens too fast and the session is not set. Is there to delay sending user to another site, perhaps by popping a modal?

Here's how I currently do it:

```
$(".myLink").click(function() {
    var soc = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  "/myAjax.php",
        data: {
            "action" : "sent",
            "social" : soc
        },
        dataType : "json"
    });
});
```

Comment: use a synchronous request for the session update? that way you won't be able to redirect until the request finishes. of course, if your users have wonky/slow network links, you're going to make things very slow/unresponsive for them.

Comment: redirect happens too fast and the session is not set - what does that mean?

Comment: @zod I think the user leaves the site before jQuery even loads/executes. Sometimes it works sometimes does not.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you would need to disable the default for the link, send the data to a php script to save the session var, and once it is completed, forward the user on. Something like this (not tested):

```
    $('a.blank').click(function(e){
        e.prevendDefault();
        $.post( "session.php", { 
            url: $(this).attr('href'), 
            id: $(this).attr('id') 
        })
        .done(function( data ) {
            window.open(this.href);
        });
    });
```

Note, you will need to check for failure and add a default behavior, so that if the php script fails for some reason, the user is still directed to the given url.